# How can I write out statuses from a json API?

Tags: json, api, status

Im trying to get server statuses to be written out on a page on my site using the steam gauge API (http://steamgaug.es/docs). I preferably want it to write out if the *ISteamClient*, *ISteamFriends*, *ISteamUser* and *IEconItems_440* servers are online or down.

I've never done anything like this before so I have no idea what to do.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to so same as on http://steamgaug.es/ page. So you may go to the this page, and view source of the page and you will see example how do they do such calls. (js is not minified and is located directly on the html page) What about statuses, as I see they just use associated array and all values are hardcoded.

Code is completely clear:

```
  var SteamServices = {

                // Actual statuses
                Translation: {
                    0 : "<span style='color:#16a085'>Online</span>",
                    1 : "<span style='color:#c0392b'>Down</span>",
                    2 : "<span style='color:#c0392b'>500 Internal Server Error</span>",
                    3 : "<span style='color:#c0392b'>Empty Response</span>",
                    4 : "<span style='color:#c0392b'>404 Not Found</span>",
                    5 : "<span style='color:#c0392b'>Timeout</span>",
                    6 : "<span style='color:#c0392b'>Unknown Error</span>"
                },

                // This does the checking
                DoCheck: function(){

                    // Show a loading message
                    $(".load-overlay").show();

                    // Load data from API
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://steamgaug.es/api",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }).done(function(data){

                        // Populate fields
                        $.each(data,function(i,v){
                            $("#"+i).html(SteamServices.Translation[v]);
                        });

                        // Hide loading message
                        $(".load-overlay").hide();

                    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {

                        // When there's an error getting the data
                        if(jqXHR.status == 502){
                            $(".load-overlay").html("<i class=\"fa fa-exclamation-triangle\"></i><br/>Service Check Error!<br/>Try again soon.");
                            $(".load-overlay").addClass("bad-load");
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

write some like below using jQuery

```
jQuery.getJSON( "http://steamgaug.es/api", function( status ) {
    if(status.ISteamClient == 0) {
      alert("ISteamClient is online");
    } else if(status.ISteamClient == 1) {
      alert("ISteamClient is Down");
    }
}
```